# How does MongoDB determine the type of a shard key?

Tags: mongodb

I am probably missing something, but I just cannot understand how MongoDB defines the key ranges, in terms of type.

Say I have a collection for user profiles that look like this:

```
{userId : "123", profiles: [p1, p2], location: "loc"}
```

Then if I declare the shard key like this:

```
{ shardcollection : "test.user_profile", key : {"userId":1} }
```

How will the ranges work:

1. If userId in {1 ... 100000}?
2. If userId is some string, like a generated UUID?

How can I define a shard key that would be treated as string, time md5 or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comparison on fields in mongo is done according the the BSON comparison order. 
See here for more details. 
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/What+is+the+Compare+Order+for+BSON+Types
and here for information on creating specific types
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Data+Types+and+Conventions

Comment: thanks, The question is if I do not define any type mongo simply treats the value as string?